# Unable to set IP address in Mininet

Tags: python, mininet

I am new to Python and Mininet. I have been trying to emulate a network topology using mininet. I am trying to assign IP addresses to each of the hosts in the network but I'm getting an attribute error.
Below is my code

```
import sys
from mininet.topo import Topo
from mininet.node import Node

class MyTopo(Topo):
    "customized topology example"
    def __init__(self):
        "custom topo creation"
        #initialize topology
        Topo.__init__(self)
        H1=self.addHost('H1')
        H3=self.addHost('H3')
        H2=self.addHost('H2')
        H4=self.addHost('H4')
        S1=self.addSwitch('S1')
        S2=self.addSwitch('S2')

        self.addLink(H1,S1, bw=10, delay='2ms')
        self.addLink(H2,S1, bw=20, delay='10ms')
        self.addLink(H3,S2, bw=10, delay='2ms')
        self.addLink(H4,S2, bw=20, delay='10ms')
        self.addLink(S1,S2, bw=20, delay='2ms', losspct=10)

        H1.setIP(self,None,'10.0.0.1',8)



topos={'mytopo':(lambda:MyTopo())}
```

I get the following error

```
Caught exception. Cleaning up...
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'setIp'
-----------------------------------------------------------------------   ---------
*** Removing excess controllers/ofprotocols/ofdatapaths/pings/noxes
killall controller ofprotocol ofdatapath ping nox_core lt-nox_core ovs- openflowd ovs-controller udpbwtest mnexec ivs 2> /dev/null
killall -9 controller ofprotocol ofdatapath ping nox_core lt-nox_core ovs openflowd ovs-controller udpbwtest mnexec ivs 2> /dev/null
pkill -9 -f "sudo mnexec"
*** Removing junk from /tmp
rm -f /tmp/vconn* /tmp/vlogs* /tmp/*.out /tmp/*.log
*** Removing old X11 tunnels
*** Removing excess kernel datapaths                                                                                                                                                
ps ax | egrep -o 'dp[0-9]+' | sed 's/dp/nl:/'                                                                                                                                       
***  Removing OVS datapathsovs-vsctl --timeout=1 list-br                                                                                                                            
*** Removing all links of the pattern foo-ethX                                                                                                                                      
ip link show | egrep -o '(\w+-eth\w+)'                                                                                                                                              
*** Cleanup complete.
```

Thanks

Comment: try to add a `print(H1)` after `H1=self.addHost('H1')` and see what kind of thing it is. it seems to be a `str`

Comment: [It is indeed a string](http://mininet.org/api/classmininet_1_1topo_1_1Topo.html#a4649e48317e0b09f84ac5c6a88424194). I'm not familiar with mininet, but [looking at the documentation](http://mininet.org/api/classmininet_1_1node_1_1Node.html#a4f399c0b11eb6358b7b9997c612ad97a) it seems that the `setIP` method is defined on `Node` objects.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that

```
mininet.topo.Topo.addHost
```

does return the Hostname(you passed to the method).
So you will have to use sth. like this:

```
self.addHost('H1')
selg.g.node['H1'].addLink(...) # maybe the part with the node['H1'] does not fit perfectly...
```

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/mininet/mininet/blob/master/mininet/topo.py) for further info.

Hint use a lot of `print()` s to get debug info.
Eg:

```
debug=True
if(debug):print(someinfo)
```

*Edit:*

maybe you might want to use

```
mininet.topo.Multigraph.add_edge
```

for this.

Answer (score 1):

H1 is indeed a string. What you can do is get the net object for H1 and then try to set the IP.

`net.get('H1').setIP(yourIP)`

Answer (score 1):

MyTopo is a class to define topology object. Host is an object attribute not a object in this instance. You can't use setIP method (of the host class) in this context.

You should set IP at the time you define the host:

```
 H1=self.addHost('H1', ip='10.0.0.1/8')
```